# How to put all body content wrapped in one div

Tags: html, css

I see a lot of responsive websites wrapping all the body content in one div, but i have no idea of how to do this. It's like when the page is loaded it fit's the screen alright, but if you zoom-out you'll see the page with all the elements in the right position, but getting little, like it's all wrapped in one div. Like this:

[image: Normal web site]

[image: Zoom-out website]

When i do a responsive-design i just make the elements fit the screen, and when you zoom-out the elements will be adjusting to the screen. How should i make it like this ? Obs: i really wanna know how to make it, without frameworks, and how should i especify the images size (with vh/vw, em, rem, %,etc).

Comment: Do you know about `media queries` ?

Comment: Shure ! What i mean is, when i use then to make the elements change size, so when i zoom-out, the elements will be adjusting themselves. I wanted to do like it's in the picture, like everything is wrapped in one element, and it just got full-size when the page loads normally.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Consider narrowing it down, or possibly trying to build the site yourself, and posting questions along with your code when you have problems. If you want to get high quality answers, consider reading the [help center tips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the screenshots it would probably have a max-width pixel dimension so when you zoom out like you've done the style sheet may be displaying a media query with, for example:

```
#container_div {max width: 1280px; margin:auto}
```

so the margin:auto would center the div (providing it was in some kind of wrapper). 
In theory this should work but I imagine there would be other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this to accomplish this goal by using bootstrap classes.
>
> if you want to set your page content in middle of page.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
   // your page content ..... 
<div>
</body>
```

> if you want to set your page content in full page.

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
   // your page content ..... 
<div>
</body>
```

> Now this container class will manage at all.